# Работа со скриптами или условным выделением в FastReport

Tags: fastreport

В одной из колонок в отчёте fastreport выводится 1 или 0. Нужно подменить 1 на Да и соответственно 0 на Нет. Не как что то не получается это сделать. Вот как я делаю это через скрипт.

```
private void Text42_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(Text42.Value.ToString() == "1")
      {
        Report.SetParameterValue("T.DPR_CONFIRM") = "Да";
      }
      else if(Text42.Value.ToString() == "0")
      {
        Report.SetParameterValue("T.DPR_CONFIRM") = "Нет";
      }
    }
```

Но пишет что setparametervalue не принимает 1 аргумент. Как это должно выглядеть и что я сделал тут не правильно? Первый раз работают со скриптом в fastreport. Или как это же условие можно сделать в условном выделении?

Comment: Откуда он берет данные "1" и "0"?

Comment: @JVic уже нашёл правильное решение.

Comment: Как вариант, в самой ячейке можно написать условие подмены использую `IIF(,,)`.

Comment: @Kromster интересный вариант а не подскажите подробно как вызвать редактор этих условий где писать iif?

Comment: @Андрей В принципе, если у вас запрос T и в нем поле DPR_CONFIRM, то можно писать вот так [IIF(<T."DPR_CONFIRM"> ='',"Да","Нет")] прямо в Text42

Comment: @Kromster немного не понял вас, вы не могли бы показать куда именно это пишется? И сам редактор желательно и что вы имели в виду под "прямо в Text42" работаю с fastreport первый раз. Так что если глупые вопросы уж извините). Желательно со скринами или подробным описанием что и как если можно.

Comment: @Андрей у ФастРепорта есть визуальный редактор, вы им пользуетесь? В нем располагаются элементы (для текста и т.п.). В элементах указывается, какие поля из каких запросов должны браться. Вот вместо поля можно указывать условия. Времени расписывать нет, дальше уж вы сами. Удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Text42_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if((decimal)Report.GetColumnValue("T.DPR_CONFIRM") == 1)
      {
        Text42.Text = "Да";
      }
      else
      {
        Text42.Text = "Нет";
      }
    }
```